# Take user input and search through a 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to make a program that takes in a string from the user, searches through a 2D array and if it matches a string in the array, print the entire row. So basically, if the user types in the name `Bobby G`, I'd like it to output `Bobby G: ugly and stupid`, if input is `Billy` it outputs `Billy: bad`, so on and so forth. Below is what I have so far. A bit of an explanation would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()  {

//!! It only works with letters of the alphabet, so if I replaced Bobby G with the  
//letter "A" It would output "ugly, and stupid", and then replace "Billy Smalls" with
//the letter "B" I'd get "Bad" so on and so forth, but I need it to work with the exact
// string, so user input of "Bobby G" outputs "ugly, and stupid"
std::string name[9][2] = {        
    {"Bobby G","ugly, and stupid"},
    {"Billy","bad"},
    {"John","smart and cool"},
    {"Adam","amzing and beautiful"},
    {"Bill","perfect"},
    {"Turner","funny"},
    {"Sonny","nice"},
    {"Jack","radical"},
    {"Frank","nice"}};

typedef std::string Full[2];

Full* last_Full = name + sizeof(name) / sizeof(Full);

struct Less {
    bool operator () (const Full& a, const string& b) const 
        {
        return a[0] < b;
        }
            };
std::string input;
std::cin >> input;

Less less_full;

Full* full = std::lower_bound(name, last_Full, input, less_full);

    if(full == last_Full || (*full)[0] != input) 
    std::cout << "Not found" << std::endl;

else std::cout << (*full)[0] << ": " << (*full)[1]  << std::endl;

system("Pause");
return 0;
}
```

I'd want to do it without nesting if statements and making it a mess.

Comment: firstly, for what you're trying to do you should use a map, hash map possibly (i.e. `unordered_map` from standard lib); secondly, you haven't specified an exact question, so you don't deserve an answer, as simple as that. "help me", "improve my code", "explain me my code" etc on `Coding Basics 101`-level code are the obvious signs you're trying to receive `tutoring` - SO is **not** a free tutoring service.

Comment: Why are you using `lower_bound` and `less`? Why not `find` or `find_if`? And use proper `begin()` and `end()`, not things like `last_Full`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task is not so simple as it seems. So I up-voted your question.

First of all it is better to use a one-dimensional array of type `std::pair<std::string, std::string>` instead of the two-dimensional array that you use.
Secondly that to apply algorithm `std::lower_bound` the array must be sorted.

The code could look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <cctype>


int main()
{
    std::pair<std::string, std::string> name[] = 
    {        
        { "Bobby G", "ugly, and stupid" },
        { "Billy", "bad" },
        { "John", "smart and cool" },
        { "Adam", "amzing and beautiful" },
        { "Bill", "perfect" },
        { "Turner", "funny" },
        { "Sonny", "nice" },
        { "Jack", "radical" },
        { "Frank", "nice" }
    };

    std::sort( std::begin( name ), std::end( name ) );

    auto compare_by_name = 
    []( const std::pair<std::string, std::string> &p1, 
        const std::pair<std::string, std::string> &p2 )
    {
        return std::lexicographical_compare( 
            p1.first.begin(), p1.first.end(), 
            p2.first.begin(), p2.first.end(),
            []( char c1, char c2 ) 
            { return std::toupper( c1 ) < std::toupper( c2 ); } );
    };

    auto p = std::make_pair( std::string( "bobby g" ), std::string( "" ) );
    auto it = std::equal_range( std::begin( name ), std::end( name ), p,
                                compare_by_name );

    if ( it.first != it.second )
    {
        std::cout << it.first->first + ' ' + it.first->second << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
Bobby G ugly, and stupid
```

it is about those participants who down voted your question.:)

If you compiler issues an error relative to array initializers you should substitute them the following way. For example

```
std::pair<std::string, std::string>( "Bobby G", "ugly, and stupid" ),
```

Here is code that uses other kind of initializers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <cctype>


int main()
{
    std::pair<std::string, std::string> name[] = 
    {        
        std::pair<std::string, std::string>( "Bobby G", "ugly, and stupid" ),
        std::pair<std::string, std::string>( "Billy", "bad" ),
        std::pair<std::string, std::string>( "John", "smart and cool" ),
        std::pair<std::string, std::string>( "Adam", "amzing and beautiful" ),
        std::pair<std::string, std::string>( "Bill", "perfect" ),
        std::pair<std::string, std::string>( "Turner", "funny" ),
        std::pair<std::string, std::string>( "Sonny", "nice" ),
        std::pair<std::string, std::string>( "Jack", "radical" ),
        std::pair<std::string, std::string>( "Frank", "nice" )
    };

    std::sort( std::begin( name ), std::end( name ) );

    auto compare_by_name = 
    []( const std::pair<std::string, std::string> &p1, 
        const std::pair<std::string, std::string> &p2 )
    {
        return std::lexicographical_compare( 
            p1.first.begin(), p1.first.end(), 
            p2.first.begin(), p2.first.end(),
            []( char c1, char c2 ) 
            { return std::toupper( c1 ) < std::toupper( c2 ); } );
    };

    auto p = std::make_pair( std::string( "bobby g" ), std::string( "" ) );
    auto it = std::equal_range( std::begin( name ), std::end( name ), p,
                                compare_by_name );

    if ( it.first != it.second )
    {
        std::cout << it.first->first + ' ' + it.first->second << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Instead of using long type name `std::pair<std::string, std::string>` you can introduce some typedef name as for example

```
typedef std::pair<std::string, std::string> Pair;
```

Here is the program that asks the user to enter a name

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <cctype>


int main()
{
    std::pair<std::string, std::string> name[] = 
    {        
        std::pair<std::string, std::string>( "Bobby G", "ugly, and stupid" ),
        std::pair<std::string, std::string>( "Billy", "bad" ),
        std::pair<std::string, std::string>( "John", "smart and cool" ),
        std::pair<std::string, std::string>( "Adam", "amzing and beautiful" ),
        std::pair<std::string, std::string>( "Bill", "perfect" ),
        std::pair<std::string, std::string>( "Turner", "funny" ),
        std::pair<std::string, std::string>( "Sonny", "nice" ),
        std::pair<std::string, std::string>( "Jack", "radical" ),
        std::pair<std::string, std::string>( "Frank", "nice" )
    };

    std::sort( std::begin( name ), std::end( name ) );

    auto compare_by_name = 
    []( const std::pair<std::string, std::string> &p1, 
        const std::pair<std::string, std::string> &p2 )
    {
        return std::lexicographical_compare( 
            p1.first.begin(), p1.first.end(), 
            p2.first.begin(), p2.first.end(),
            []( char c1, char c2 ) 
            { return std::toupper( c1 ) < std::toupper( c2 ); } );
    };

    while ( true )
    {
        std::cout << "Enter name: ";
        std:: string s;
        std::getline( std::cin, s );

        if ( s.empty() ) break;

        auto p = std::make_pair( s, std::string( "" ) );
        auto it = std::equal_range( std::begin( name ), std::end( name ), p,
                                    compare_by_name );

        if ( it.first != it.second )
        {
            std::cout << it.first->first + ' ' + it.first->second << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "The name is not found" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: hmmm well in the updated post im not getting any for the red squiggly errors, but when it compiles i get a fatal error shown below

Comment: fatal error C1075: end of file found before the left brace '{' at 'c:\users\tobi\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\revision\revision\revision.cpp(10)' was matched

Comment: I did :/        I am using Microsoft visual C++ 2010 express, so perhaps there is a more advanced compiler you could suggest that may solve the problem

Comment: @Tobi You should copy all my headers in your program after microsoft header "stdafx.h". And then you should copy the body of my main into the body of your main. The error message says that you even unable copy and paste the code. So the number of open braces do not correspond to the number of closing braces.

Comment: idk what i did wrong but it compiles now which is great! but i am cant really type anything in- it only says "bobby g ugly, stupid" and then press any key to continue.

Comment: @Tobi because I explicitly specified this name. You should change the program such a way that the user could enter the name that he wants to find.

Comment: i tried simply just asking for cin<<name and also removing you bobby g, but it didnt work. I've been trying something like this for days, almost a week and havent been able to

Comment: yes sir!

    std::string in;
    auto p = std::make_pair( std::string( in ), std::string( in& ) );  //implemented user input into auto specifier
    auto it = std::equal_range( std::begin( name ), std::end( name ), p,
                                compare_by_name );
 std::string in;
 cin>>in;
    if ( it.first != it.second && it.first==in) // user input into condicional, but i am getting red squigly linees under == which is an error
    {
        std::cout << it.first->first + ' ' + it.first->second << std::endl;
    }
 system("Pause");
    return 0;
}

Comment: how can i get show it to you in proper coding format instead of the mess above, should we move to chat?

Comment: @Tobi  You may not substitute function std::getline for the operator >>.

Comment: I honestly don't know what to do

Comment: @Tobi All you need is to copy paste and use.

Comment: you are THE man. I have been stumped on this for days. this may be trivial for you but I'm learning and experimenting at the same time. I usually don't go around asking for help, but I was so keen on solving this i found no where else to go. Dude, thank you for being so patient and supportive, you've truly earned that 31.6k. I'd vote up but I don't have the reputation, but its definitely worthy of being the answer. Thanks for being kind and helping me out, lemme know if you ever need help ;)

Comment: I've actually just run into a bit of a problem! I can't add new people nor can i edit the existing names of the people. If i do i get Debug assertion failed! and then Expression:sequence not ordered

Answer (score 2):

I'm really having a hard time understanding what you wrote in your code but according to the description this should go something like ([demo](http://ideone.com/ctikkk)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

int main(void) {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> name = {        
    {"Bobby G","ugly, and stupid"},
    {"Billy","bad"},
    {"John","smart and cool"},
    {"Adam","amzing and beautiful"},
    {"Bill","perfect"},
    {"Turner","funny"},
    {"Sonny","nice"},
    {"Jack","radical"},
    {"Frank","nice"}};

    std::string in;
    std::getline(std::cin,in);
    if(name.count(in)){
        std::cout << in << " " << name[in] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And to save us headache in the future indent your code and don't make it look like ASCII art...

---

So basically what we use is an [unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) which holds the names as keys and the sentences as values.

Then we use [cin](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin) to receive input from the user and place it into `string in`.

The last step is to check whether we have such a string as a key in the map using [`count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/count) which will return `1` iff it contains this key.

But seriously, you have to do your reading more seriously; find a tutorial and/or a book and get your concepts straight.

Comment: @vaxquis I was just editing it's just that the `string[9][2]` initialization begged to paste a `map` there and just call count, so I am in the middle of explaining FYI..

Comment: as you can probably see in the comments below the "question", the very same thought (the `map` one) occurred to me - so you're probably a nice and reasonable person, and thus receive my Powerful +1 Vote of Good Faith *chuckles*

Comment: @vaxquis I hope my edit is not disappointing, I did my best :) 
Anyway if there something missing feel free to comment or suggest edits... There's not much of a _question_ here but maybe being nice to newbies will encourage them to go in the right path (or it's just me being optimistic).

Comment: @Scis thanks, but when i try what you did, I get an error right at the beginning of the initialization of the start of the map saying "Error: initialization with {...}is not allowed with object of type "std::tr1::unordered_map...."

Comment: @Tobi what environment are you using ?

Comment: @Scis Microsoft visual C++ 2010 express

Comment: *chuckle chuckle* as far as my experience goes, I'd say it's just you being optimistic; people always learn the hard way - if it were the other way around, every human being would have transcended already... when I was a newbie, I read books, manuals and tutorials - not asked "questions". Nb, MSVC++ compilers/library were notorious for its C++11 compatibility - *or lack of it*, so to speak.

Comment: BTW, @Tobi - I'd strongly suggest starting with eg. `Algorithms + Data Structures = Programs` - it's old, but it does its job ; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_%2B_Data_Structures_%3D_Programs

Comment: @Tobi Why not use [VS2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40787) Express ? Anyway if that's not an option you'll just need to initialize the map using [`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) (e.g `name["Billy"]="bad";` etc..). The problem you're experiencing is due to VS2010's [lack of support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx#corelanguagetable) of (not so) new c++ features...

Comment: @Scis it worked, thanks, but I cant get it to work with last name, so Bobby G wont work, only bobby. Is there a way I can do it including the whitespacing?

Comment: @Tobi Sure, use [getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) e.g: `std::getline(std::cin,in);` I've updated the example...

Comment: @Scis this is just what i needed. Thank you so much for your time and patience I really appreciate it!!